# How many ways 3 person can split a $\$50$ dinner bill such that two person each pay an odd number of dollars and one person pays at least $\$5$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Determine how many ways Brian, Katie, and Charlie can split a $\$50$ dinner bill such that Brian and Katie each pay an odd number of dollars and Charlie pays at least $\$5$.

---

How can I use generating functions to solve this problem? Or should I use a counting approach?

Comment: The generating-function approach would be to say that we're looking for the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $$ (x^1+x^3+x^5+\cdots)(x^1+x^3+x^5+\cdots)(x^5+x^6+x^7+\cdots) $$ But I'm not sure that will be easier than the straightforward combinatorial solution in Joffan's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Take $\$6$ off Charlie and a dollar off the other two. Now lay out the remaining $\$42$ in $21$ $\$2$ chits and divide those. By stars-and-bars, there are

$${21+2 \choose 2} = 253\text{ options}$$

I'll leave the generating functions to someone else...

Comment: (+1) Well, other than $\binom{23}{2}=253$, your answer is correct. $210=\binom{21}{2}$.

Comment: @robjohn thanks

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for the number of ways that the three can pay a bill of $n$ dollars is
$$
\begin{align}
&(x+x^3+x^5+\dots)(x+x^3+x^5+\dots)(x^5+x^6+x^7+\dots)\\[3pt]
&=x^7\frac1{(1-x^2)^2}\frac1{1-x}\\
&=x^7\frac1{(1-x)^3}\frac1{(1+x)^2}\\
&=x^7\left[\frac14\frac1{(1-x)^3}+\frac14\frac1{(1-x)^2}+\frac3{16}\frac1{1-x}+\frac18\frac1{(1+x)^2}+\frac3{16}\frac1{1+x}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\small\left[\frac14(-1)^k\binom{-3}{k}+\frac14(-1)^k\binom{-2}{k}+\frac3{16}(-1)^k\binom{-1}{k}+\frac18\binom{-2}{k}+\frac3{16}\binom{-1}{k}\right]x^{k+7}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\small\left[\frac14\binom{k+2}{2}+\frac14\binom{k+1}{1}+\frac3{16}\binom{k}{0}+\frac18(-1)^k\binom{k+1}{1}+\frac3{16}(-1)^k\binom{k}{0}\right]x^{k+7}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{16}\left[(2k^2+10k+11)+(-1)^k(2k+5)\vphantom{\frac1{16}}\right]x^{k+7}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\binom{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}{2}+2\binom{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}{1}+\binom{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}{0}\right]x^{k+7}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\lfloor k/2\rfloor+2}{2}x^{k+7}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging $k=43$ into $(1)$ yields the coefficient of $x^{50}$ to be $253$.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question, you should know some knowledge:

$1)$ Sum of Infinite Progression Series Formula:

$$ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots=\frac{a}{1-r}$$
where $a$ is the first term, and $r$ is the common ratio.

$2)$ Some important expressions for solving this question:

(i) $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^2=\binom11 +\binom21 x+ \binom31 x^2 +\binom41 x^3+\cdots$$

where the coefficient for $x^k$ is $\binom{k+1}{1}$.

(ii) $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^3=\binom22 +\binom32 x+ \binom42 x^2 +\binom52 x^3 +\cdots$$

where the coefficient for $x^k$ is $\binom{k+2}{2}$.

(iii) $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^4=\binom33 +\binom43 x+ \binom53 x^2 +\binom64 x^3 +\cdots$$

where the coefficient for $x^k$ is $\binom{k+3}{3}$.

(iv) $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^n=\binom{n-1}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n-1}x+ \binom{n+1}{n-1} x^2 +\binom{n+2}{n-1} x^3+\cdots$$

where the coefficient for $x^k$ is $\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$.

---

Back to the question, we know the generating function for the number of ways that the three can pay a bill of $n$ dollars is

$$\begin{align}
(x+x^3+x^5+\cdots)^2(x^5+x^6+x^7+\cdots)\\
=\left(\frac{x}{(1-x^2)}\right)^2\frac{x^5}{1-x}\\
=\frac{x^7}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x^5)}\\
=\frac{x^7}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x)}\frac{1+x}{1+x}\\
=\frac{x^7+x^8}{(1-x^2)^3}\\
\end{align}$$

Since $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^3}$ has only even-powered terms, the $x^7$ will not contribute to the $x^{50}$ coefficient due to parity, so we only consider $x^8$.

The $x^{50}$ coefficient of this function is the $x^{42}$ coefficient of $\frac 1{(1-x^2)^3}$.

To easy our calculations, we can let $y=x^2$ and our functions will become

$$\frac 1{(1-y)^3}=\left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right)^3=(1+y+y^2+y^3+\cdots)^3$$

We need to find the coefficient of $y^{21}$ in $\frac 1{(1-y)^3}$, this is $\binom{21+2}{2}=253.$